# Python 3.7.4 No module named tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm getting started using python on Mac, and I keep getting "No module named 'tkinter'"

I tried installing tkinter using
    
`brew install python3-tk`

Brew could not find a pack by that name.

And according to [this page](https://www.python.org/download/mac/tcltk/#built-in-8-6-8) anyways "As of Python 3.7.0, 3.6.8, and 2.7.16, all current Python installers for macOS downloadable from python.org supply their own private copies of Tcl/Tk 8.6.8."

But when I check in terminal for tkinter i get this
    
`python -m tkinter
$/usr/bin/python: No module named tkinter`

Comment: What version of Python are you working with, and where did you get it? Did you install it from python.org?

Comment: What does the command `python --version` print out? Mostly likely, without realizing it you are running python 2 instead of 3.

Comment: Oh snap! it printed out `Python 2.7.10` haha. Is there a way to switch to the one I downloaded (python 3)?